# How can I view all the properties of a given JS object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a 3rd party server side control that generates JavaScript and I'd like to see what methods and properties it exposes.

Currently I just type in an invalid function like `asdf123()` so VS will break and I can add a watch to the variable, but there are a ton of methods and I don't know what I'm looking for (I'm trying to make the control do something undocumented).

What's the best way to approach this until the vendor responds to my help request?

Comment: Firebug for Firefox with the DOM tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way could be to use firebug(firefox) or debugbar (ie) or you can look into this article where a method tells u the properties of a object

http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256BF8004D72D6

Answer (score 1):

```
console.dir(myobject);
```

Then open the console in Chrome and you will have a nice tree structure of your object.
(note: myobject is the identifier that references the object that you want to inspect).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
str = ""
for (x in obj){
  str = str + obj[x];
}
alert(str);//or doc.write it somewhere
```